# Memory leaks when using UIImagePickerController in camera mode

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, uiimagepickercontroller, ios10, photolibrary

This is a simple single view, single `ViewController` test app. This app has one button in the `ViewController`. Accessing the `PhotoLibrary` does not show any leaks, but the `camera` shows some leaks when presented and more when dismissed.

Here is code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    let pickerCntrl = UIImagePickerController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        pickerCntrl.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
    @IBAction func takePic(_ sender: Any) {
        pickerCntrl.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        pickerCntrl.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
        pickerCntrl.allowsEditing = true
        if (UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)){
            self.present(pickerCntrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
//        let editedCapture = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as! UIImage?
//        let origCapture = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage?
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

**ScreenShot :** 
[image]

Comment: The function references refer to functions in the CoreAnimation and CoreGraphics libraries so these appaer to be issues internal to iOS itself. theres likely nothing you can do about these except maybe raise them on the apple forms or submit a bug. Your not using these libraries directly so the issue seems to be out of your control

Comment: Seems to be a relatively new issue. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, probably introduced in one of the latest releases, or change to swift 3

Comment: Have you got any solution to this? I'm having the same issue.